# How to convert values of a column into a new rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a huge pandas dataflame such as

```
    A   B   C   D   E
0:  a0  b0  c0  d0  e0
1:  a1  b1  c1  d1  e1
2:  a2  b2  c2  d2  e2
```

I want to change it into:

```
    A   B   C   X   Y
0:  a0  b0  c0  D   d0
0:  a0  b0  c0  E   e0
1:  a1  b1  c1  D   d1
1:  a1  b1  c1  E   e2
2:  a2  b2  c2  D   d1
2:  a2  b2  c2  E   e2
```

How can I do that?

So far I am creating a new dataFrame and populating it with a for-loop.

Comment: you can use melt here: `df.melt(['A','B','C'],var_name='X',value_name='Y')`

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can do via set index, and stack:

```
df = (df.set_index(list('ABC'))
        .stack()
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={'level_3': 'X', 0: 'Y'})
)


    A   B   C  X   Y
0  a0  b0  c0  D  d0
1  a0  b0  c0  E  e0
2  a1  b1  c1  D  d1
3  a1  b1  c1  E  e1
4  a2  b2  c2  D  d2
5  a2  b2  c2  E  e2
```

Comment: I think the solution with melt is more elegant and intuitive. Thank you in any case